# typescript extract substring using regular expressions in TypeScript

Tags: regex, typescript

I'm trying to use regular expressions in TypeScript to

1. Check if a given string matches an expression
2. Extract a substring

These are the two strings I'm trying to match against
`Total Order <orderId>`
ex: `Total Order order1`, I should be able to extract `order1` from the regular expression

The other string I'm trying to match against is.  I have been trying to do this without any success, I came across the following but no success
[How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression), but this is different from what I'm trying to do.

`Items Order <orderId>`, the  could have spaces as well
ex: `Items Order order1`. I should be able to extract `order1` from this again.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Regexp Match:

```
const str = 'Items Order order1';
const matches = str.match(/Items\sOrder\s(\w+)/);
if (matches) {
    console.log(matches[1]); // ordem1    
}
```

if the `matches` variable is filled, then a valid content will be available in the second position of the array (group captured).